# Position: absolute making the image take the whole page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got a slider banner, it works perfectly, but i need to put an posiiton:absolute to put one div above another, and when i do it, it just ignore the width and height i designed for the img, and make the img occupate the whole screen. Could someone help me ?

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="eight columns all">
    <img src="img/slide_1.jpg" class="hide" id="img-slide">
    <img src="img/slide_2.jpg" class="hide" id="img-slide">
    <img src="img/slide_3.jpg" class="hide" id="img-slide">
    <!--<p>>></p> -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.all img{
    margin:15px;
    height: 95%;
    width:95%;
    border-radius:5px;
    position:absolute;
}

    .all img.show{
        opacity:1;
        left: 0px;
        -webkit-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
        transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;

    }

    .all img.hide{
        left: -1000px;
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
        transition:all 1.0s ease-in-out;
    }
```

And the JS:

```
function loop() {
    var listPict = document.getElementsByClassName('all')[0].children;

    var old = listPict.length - 1;

    var current = 0;

    listPict[current].setAttribute('class', 'show');

    listPict[old].setAttribute('class', 'hide');

    old = current;
    current++;

    if (current === listPict.length)
        current = 0;

    setTimeout(loop, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `absolute` positioning, the percentages for the `height` and `width` will reflect the size of the *offsetParent*, which in your case is probably `<body>`. This means e.g. `width: 95%;` is *95% of the width of the page*.

You will either need to define the sizes in pixels or give some ancestor node, e.g. `div.all`, relative positioning to make this into the *offsetParent*, so that the sizes are bound to that instead of `<body>`

```
div.all {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I also had tried this, but when i add it, the slides don't show up ! And when i put the size in px, it still don't change... And i don't know any other way to put the divs together !

Comment: Also, it just "breaks" the coulmn that is on the side of the slides... I'm using skeleton framework, and it seems to break all of the columns scheme

Comment: In addition, the images may not show up because with all the content taken out of the flow of the div.all it may collapse to 0 height. Add a height rule to that selector too to give div.all the height you want the image to take up 95% of.